# readfile() turn out a file with zero byte in downloaded

Tags: php

In my download PHP file:

```
ob_start();
set_time_limit(0);
// PHP CODE //
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($thisFileName));
header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Connection: close');
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($dwfile);
exit();
```

in PHP.ini

```
output_buffering = 4096
upload_max_filesize = 200M
max_execution_time = 120  
max_input_time = 60
```

I was doing this in a localhost under a MS Windows platform, file was uploaded with the correct size, but once I tried to download a file (like 10MB) from it, the file was downloaded in zero byte.

I also tested with a approximate 5MB file, it was correctly downloaded.

thanks

Comment: Try to define the `Content-Length` header: `header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($dwfile));`

Comment: the file was downloaded, file size shown it original size but empty contents.